# iframe refuses to display Firefox Can’t Open This Page

Tags: iframe

I am trying to load website "apkpure.com" on iframe into one of my web pages but it is not displaying.

I am getting this error in Firefox:
Firefox Can’t Open This Page

To protect your security, apkpure.com will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.

Learn more…

Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious sites

```
<iframe src="https://apkpure.com/" width="680" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How can this problem be bypassed?

thanks

Comment: How about Chrome? Edge?

Comment: the same problem

Comment: In the error message: *`"... if another site has embedded it."`* so your iframe is actually pointing to a site that has another site in an iframe? If so, I suspect some illicit shenanigans?

Comment: I do not think the site is protected and does not accept its inclusion in iframe Is there a way to bypass this?